# How to identify a view in a android app?

Tags: android, robotium

Recently,I am developing a automated tool(like [monkey](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html)) with [robotium](https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium). If one view has be visited and next time it will  be visited with little probability. To Identify a view, I try to use view.hashCode(), view.getId(), but it seams bad. So my problem is *how can I identify a view in a app?*

Comment: You can use set/getTag method

Comment: Sorry, it does not work while the app has multi acitivities because when the activity desctroy, the tag will be deleted